# Can I use FileSystem to download a pdf file to local device in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have to download a pdf file from web and save it to the local storage. I try it with `FileSystem.downloadAsync` but the file isn't found in the directory. Here is my code.

```
    _download(){
    FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      'https://cs.wmich.edu/~alfuqaha/spring18/cs5560/lectures/angular4_tutorial.pdf',
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'angular.pdf'
    )
    alert("download successful!")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Photos will be saved in the `documentDirectory` when running through the **Expo app**, but you cannot access Expo’s `documentDirectory` through other apps on your phone - this is just part of the `Android OS`.

If you want to save it locally, You have to `eject` the project.

and you can install `npm install --save react-native-fetch-blob`

[directions for use](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)